# why echo "abc\r\c" and echo "abc\rc\c" && sleep 1 behave differently in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

When I run `echo -e "abc\r\c"` in bash, it does not output anything; but when I run `echo -e "abc\r\c" && sleep 1`, it first output `abc`, and then clear the output after one second. So why adding a `&& sleep 1` make this difference?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with bash

Answer (score 4):

The first one *does* output something: the characters a, b and c followed by a carriage return. The `\c` suppresses all further output, including the newline that `echo` normally prints after its arguments (You can get the same effect with `echo -ne "abc\r"`). Then after the command exits, the shell prints out your prompt. Because of the carriage return and no newline, this overwrites the 'abc'. If your prompt is shorter than what is printed out, you'll see the leftover characters after the prompt.

With the second one, adding the `sleep 1` causes a delay before the commands exit, giving you time to see the text before it's overwritten with a shell prompt.

Comment: Interesting point about the `\c` . Do you by chance know what `\c` is **really** good for? Suppressing the newline is already caused by using `-n`, so what additional bonus does a `\c` have?

Comment: @user1934428 I don't have the foggiest idea about its purpose.

Comment: @Shawn I got it. When a command exits, if the prompt is not at the end of the current line, the characters before it will be printed and the others will be supressed, Right?

Comment: `-n` is a `bash` extension, while `\c` is defined by POSIX. Keep in mind that the POSIX specification for `echo` was just a best attempt at standardizing what was a large number of incompatible existing implementations. When possible, use `printf` instead of `echo` (and it is virtually always possible).

Comment: The intended purpose of `\c` is to simply suppress the trailing newline; it's almost a side-effect that it will suppress anything following the `\c` as well. (There's no *reason* to put anything after `\c`, but there's also no reason to make it a syntax error or similar, so simply treating it as "stop printing now" is the most reasonable action to take.)